# What combination of labels to use to let NGINX connect to socket in /home/user?

Tags: nginx, selinux

I'm running a uwsgi app that creates a unix socket in `/home/user/myapp.sock` and nginx has been given the right permissions to access the file, however, selinux isn't letting me connect to it:

```
avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=11246 comm="nginx" name="myapp.sock"
```

My `/home/user` dir is labeled as:

```
drwxr-x---.  6 hibasa hibasa unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0  4096 feb 13 09:14 .
```

and the socket:

```
srw-rw-rw-.  1 hibasa hibasa unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0     0 feb 13 08:59 myapp.sock
```

But what is the correct combination of labels for the parent dir and the socket to let NGINX connect to it?

Everything works fine if I just `setenforce 0` as root but I don't really want to disable SELinux completely

Comment: Do you have a (more) complete AVC message (audit log `/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?